# Socialite Google sign in throws InvalidStateException because of profile

Tags: php, laravel, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I am using `Laravel 5.8` and `Socialite 4.1`.

I want to enable `Facebook` and `Google` sign in on my website.

`Facebook` sign in works, but `Google` sign in throws `InvalidStateException`

The funny thing is, if I comment out `profile` in the `$scopes` array in `\laravel\socialite\src\Two\GoogleProvider.php` like so:

```
protected $scopes = [
        'openid',
        //'profile',
        'email',
    ];
```

Then it works, but then I just get the user's email and not the actual profile.

I've contacted socialite on github but to no avail, I've made oauth credentials 
 with multiple gmail accounts but all to no avail, always `Facebook` works but `Google` works only **without** profile.

Comment: I don't see your name in Laravel Socialite github repo issues.

Comment: @nmfzone https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/389